# What does fpstrict do in Java?

Tags: java, floating-point

I read the [JVM specification for the `fpstrict` modifier](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Overview.doc.html#28905) but still don't fully understand what it means.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It's probably useful that the corresponding Java keyword is `strictfp` and **not** `fpstrict`, as one might assume.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, it mandates that calculations involving the affected `float` and `double` variables have to follow the IEEE 754 spec to the letter, including for intermediate results.

This has the effect of:

- Ensuring that the same input will always generate exactly the same result on all systems
- The CPU may have to do some extra work, making it slightly slower
- The results will be, in some cases, *less* accurate (much less, in extreme cases)

**Edit:**
More specifically, many modern CPUs use 80 bit floating point arithmetic (["extended precision"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision)) internally. Thus, they can internally represent some numbers in denormalized form that would cause arithmetic overflow or underflow (yielding Infinity or zero, respectively) in 32 or 64bit floats; in borderline cases, 80 bit just allows to retain more precision. When such numbers occur as intermediate results in a calculation, but with an end result inside the range of numbers that can represented by 32/64bit floats, then you get a "more correct" result on machines that use 80bit float arithmetic than on machines that don't - or in code that uses `strictfp`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In what cases might a floating point calculation differ from the IEEE754 spec?

Answer (score 6):

I like this answer, which hits the point:

> It ensures that your calculations are equally wrong on all platforms.

Answer (score 3):

`strictfp` is a keyword and can be used to modify a class or a method, but never a
variable. Marking a class as strictfp means that any method code in the class will
conform to the *IEEE 754* standard rules for floating points. Without that modifier,
floating points used in the methods might behave in a platform-dependent way.
If you don't declare a class as strictfp, you can still get strictfp behavior on a
method-by-method basis, by declaring a method as strictfp.

If you don't know the *IEEE 754* standard, now's not the time to learn it. You have, as we say, bigger fish to fry.